# SQLPlus client cannot run even when LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sqlplus

I'm trying to execute sqlplus from terminal. I already defined bash_profile adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH lines below:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_12_2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

calling sqlplus I get this error:

```
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is solved only when I explicitly export path on terminal:

export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_12_2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

If I already defined that on bash_profile, why the error persists?

P.S: After changes I logout reboot my machine to refresh environment. But no success.

Comment: Use ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile and put there export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/instantclient_12_2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}.
Mention the dot before the names of the environment files.

Comment: It works .So, why bashrc is preferred over bash_profile?

Comment: .bash_profile is executed once upon login. You can put there mem, cpu or disk stats. On the other hand .bashrc is executed on both login and other  methods of shell calls. I mean sudo, /bin/bash etc. As You stated above all .bashrc just simply works.

Comment: .bash_profile is the correct way because .bashrc is not supposed to be executed in noninteractive shells. So if you do `ssh hostname sqlplus` only .bash_profile gets sourced.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend to You setting variable $ORACLE_HOME in Your .bashrc. The .bashrc (mention the dot prior to bashrc) should be placed in Your home directory. Use command cd to get there (no parameters).

```
export $ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/instantclient_12_2
```

Then just use it in Your .bashrc as follows:

```
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$ORACLE_HOME/bim:$PATH
```

that should resolve Your issue.

If not, consider using LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and point it to desired .so library.

E.g.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: .bash_profile is the correct way because .bashrc is not supposed to be executed in noninteractive shells. So if you do `ssh hostname sqlplus` only .bash_profile gets sourced.